# Path Error when running Gekko Optimization Solver

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

Running the attached code results in the below error. The error is the same even if changing `m.options.SOLVER` to 2 or 3

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\17576\Documents\Python\Scratch.py", line 33, in 
> m.solve()   File "C:\Users\17576\Documents\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\gekko\gekko.py",
> line 2227, in solve
> self.load_JSON()   File "C:\Users\17576\Documents\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\gekko\gk_post_solve.py",
> line 13, in load_JSON
> f = open(os.path.join(self._path,'options.json')) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> 'C:\Users\17576\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpp6w85mm5gk_model0\options.json'
>
> Error: The system cannot find the path specified.
>
> Error: 'results.json' not found. Check above for additional error
> details
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

```
from gekko import GEKKO

# Variables
var_a = 155.31
var_b = 6.27
var_c = 12
var_d = 750
var_e = 10
var_f = 1
var_d_lower_bound_percentage = .99
var_e_lower_bound_percentage = .99
var_e_upper_bound_percentage = 1.01
x_value = 1
y_value = 3

# Optimization
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

x = m.Var(value=x_value, lb=0)
y = m.Var(value=y_value, lb=0, integer=True)

m.Equation(x*var_a + y*var_b <= var_d)
m.Equation(x*var_a + y*var_b >= var_d*var_d_lower_bound_percentage)

m.Equation(((x*var_a)/(x*var_a + y*var_b)) + ((y*var_b)/(x*var_a + y*var_b)) == 1)

m.Equation(((x*var_a)/(x*var_a + y*var_b))*var_f + ((y*var_b)/(x*var_a + y*var_b))*var_c <= var_e*var_e_upper_bound_percentage)
m.Equation(((x*var_a)/(x*var_a + y*var_b))*var_f + ((y*var_b)/(x*var_a + y*var_b))*var_c >= var_e*var_e_lower_bound_percentage)

m.Obj(((x*var_a)/(x*var_a + y*var_b))*var_f + ((y*var_b)/(x*var_a + y*var_b))*var_c)

m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve()

print(x.value)
print(y.value)
```

Comment: Surely there's more to that error? Like, I would assume there's some context that appeared beforehand...

Comment: This is the only other context: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\17576\Documents\Python\Scratch.py", line 33, in <module>
    m.solve()
  File "C:\Users\17576\Documents\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\gekko\gekko.py", line 2227, in solve
    self.load_JSON()
  File "C:\Users\17576\Documents\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\gekko\gk_post_solve.py", line 13, in load_JSON
    f = open(os.path.join(self._path,'options.json'))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\17576\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpb0n_da1ogk_model0\\options.json'`

Comment: Please put errors  and code into the question itself as formatted text, never in comments.

Comment: Anyway, it's telling you that `options.json` is missing. That's the same error that was in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60649331/python-gekko-cant-find-options-json-file). You didn't mention you'd looked up anything previously or made any kind of research effort, so also make sure to update your post if you've tried the solutions at that link already.

Comment: I added the full message in the body of the question. I mentioned in the question that I tried one of those solves and the other I just tried (bounding decision variables) and still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading the version of `gekko`. See instructions on [managing packages](https://apmonitor.com/pds/index.php/Main/InstallPythonPackages) if additional support is needed.

```py
pip install gekko --upgrade
```

Both remote and local solutions complete successfully with `gekko` version 1.0.5. From the path error, it appears that it is either an older version or else there is a permission error with writing to the tmp run directory folder on your Windows computer.

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 APMonitor, Version 1.0.0
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :  0
   Constants    :  0
   Variables    :  6
   Intermediates:  0
   Connections  :  0
   Equations    :  6
   Residuals    :  6
 
 Number of state variables:    6
 Number of total equations: -  5
 Number of slack variables: -  4
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :    -3
 
 * Warning: DOF <= 0
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I:  0 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    5 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    2 Obj:  9.90E+00 Gap:       NaN
--Integer Solution:   9.90E+00 Lowest Leaf:   9.90E+00 Gap:   0.00E+00
Iter:     2 I:  0 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    5 Dpth:    1 Lvs:    2 Obj:  9.90E+00 Gap:  0.00E+00
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :  0.0156 sec
 Objective      :  9.9
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------

[0.91446827259]
[96.0]
```

**Update**

It appears that there is an error with running the `apm` executable locally for `JackW24`, but not with the cloud-based service (default option) with `remote=True`. An error with running locally can be diagnosed by running the executable such as the following for Linux:

```bash
user@domain:/$ cd /home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gekko/bin/
user@domain:~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gekko/bin$ ./apm
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 APMonitor, Version 1.0.1
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 
 @error: Model File Not Found
 Model file does not exist: model.apm
 STOPPING...
```

If there is a different result than this, it indicates that there is a problem with running `remote=False`.

Comment: I upgraded and am still getting the same error. How would you recommend I approach determining if it is a permission error?

Comment: Try the command m.open_folder() to see if the files are written to the directory. Another potential issue is that apm.exe is prevented from running although I haven’t seen that error previously. Are you on a corporate computer with restrictive policies?

Comment: If the problem runs successfully with remote=True then it is likely a tmp folder permission error. If it is only with remote=False then it is likely an executable blocked. What is the version of Python?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, it is not a corporate computer, it is personal and i haven't set any restrictions. And I have Python 3.10

Comment: Do you get an error with remote=True?

Comment: I do not get an error with remote=True

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, unfortunately. Could you try running `apm.exe` that is in the python Lib/site-packages/gekko/bin folder? There may be an error with running the local executable on your computer. If there is an error, please send any message that it returns to a `cmd` prompt.

Comment: `JackW24` - I added a method that has helped me diagnose local run issues. See `update`.